# The inner product spaces and linearity in probability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Consider a class of inner product spaces

$$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_{{\lambda}\in  \Lambda}: R^n\times R^n\to R$$

parameterized by $\lambda \in \Lambda=\Delta(\{w_1,....,w_n\})$, the set of all probability distributions on the $n$ dimensional finite support.

Now suppose the class of norms $\|x\|_{\lambda}=\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle_{\lambda}}$ satisfies the following linearity in probability assumption: for all $x\in R^n$ and all $\alpha\in [0,1]$, it holds

$$\alpha\langle x,x \rangle_{\lambda_1}+(1-\alpha)\langle x,x \rangle_{\lambda_2}=\langle x,x \rangle_{\alpha\lambda_1+(1-\alpha)\lambda_2}, \phantom{000} \forall \lambda_1, \lambda_2\in \Lambda$$

What additional assumptions are needed in order to conclude that the inner product space with parameter $\lambda$ must have the form of $L_2(\lambda)$, i.e.

$$\langle x,y\rangle_{\lambda}=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i y_i$$
?

Would Riesz Theorem or other existing characterization of $L_2(\lambda)$ be useful? Thanks.

Suppose in $R^2$,   for all $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$, $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$, we have

$$\langle( 1-\lambda_1, \lambda_1),(1,-1)\rangle_{\lambda}=0$$

Can we conclude the functional form of $\langle.,.\rangle_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$?

Comment: Is the linearity condition $\langle x,x \rangle_{\lambda_1}+\langle x,x \rangle_{\lambda_2}=\langle x,x \rangle_{\alpha\lambda_1+(1-\alpha)\lambda_2}$ correct? If I let $\alpha = 0$, I get $\langle x,x\rangle_{\lambda_1} = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: oh, sorry,... it has $\alpha, 1-\alpha$ on the l.h.s.

Comment: what is $\Delta$?

Comment: Hi,  $\Delta$ is the probability simplex in $R^n$, i.e. for any $\lambda$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$ and $\lambda_i\geq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: and what is $\Delta(\{w_1,\dotsc, w_n\})$? Anyway. $\Delta$ is just the convex hull of $\{e_1, \dotsc, e_n\}$. So you obtain $$ \langle x, x \rangle_\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \langle x, x \rangle_{e_i}. $$ I doubt that you can say something about $\langle x, y \rangle_\lambda$ in general

Comment: or probably I just don't understand your question

Comment: $\Delta$ is indeed the set as you mentioned. Maybe the question I plan to ask is that how could I select L2 space from the class of all inner product spaces.